# Accessing User 'Most Listened To' using Spotify / Echo Nest / Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, history, spotify

I want to know if I can access a user's play history (more specifically what songs they listen to the most) for an app.  The app I am building can perform the same goal with iTunes using their built-in play counter.  I know Spotify uses a similar counter, but I assume for privacy concerns they don't want to deal with privacy concerns from concerned users.  However, I saw a few instances where it was suggested that this task could be accomplished using Facebook's API, or Echo Nest's API.  Please let me know if anyone has some constructive suggestions toward finding a way to legally obtain a particular users 'most listened to songs', or something to that effect.

SB

Answer (score 0):

There's some documentation about *Open Graph Music* on the Facebook Developer homepage:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

Baseline is that you only can request a User's play history if he gave you app the explicit right to read his data.

The relevant permissions would be

- `user_actions.music` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_actions_music
- `user_actions:{app_namespace}` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_actions__app_namespace_

Then, you should be able to request

```
GET /me/music.listens
```

according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/music.listens/ You'll need to perform the aggregation of the most played songs/artists yourself, because there's no endpoint for that.